# Chartboost campaign not serving ads in iOS

Tags: lua, coronasdk, ads, interstitial, chartboost

I'm attempting to get my app to serve interstitial ads (video and static) using a cross-promotional chartboost campaign. I feel as though I've set up everything correctly, because my dashboard on the website indicates that the SDK has been integrated for that app, and when I put the app in test mode, it receives test ads. However, when I turn off test mode, I receive no ads. My app was built in Corona SDK, and I'm using the chartboost plugin made [by swipeware, shown here.](https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/chartboost/index.html) I'm using the demo project on their [github page](https://github.com/swipeware/CoronaChartboostPlugin). I think the problem MUST be with the way my campaigns on chartboost are set up, but I don't know why. Can anyone give me a hint? [I've made images out of what shows on my dashboard on Chartboost --](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfLwe.jpg) seems to me that campaigns like FE_Stories_4_11_Test, whose details are also shown, should be showing ads nonstop. Is there any reason this wouldn't happen?

https://github.com/swipeware/CoronaChartboostPlugin